# Does old compiled code have benefits from compact strings on latest jre?

Tags: java, performance, bytecode

Assume i have some old code compiled by previous versions compilers. Will it get benefit from improvements `String` class less memory consumption or i need recompile it with latest jdk?

Comment: Changes to the inner workings of a class allow all other classes  using them to benefit from these changes. That’s the whole point of encapsulation in OOP and using libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, old bytecode will benefit from the Compact String optimization without recompilation. This is because it is a change to the implementation of the String class itself. The bytecode format is still fairly high level and abstracts away the actual implementation of Strings, Objects, etc.

However, there is another change ([JEP280](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/280)) which does require recompilation to benefit from. In previous versions of Java, nonconstant string concatenation was compiled to a series of calls to StringBuilder (or StringBuffer) under the hood. So code like `"I have " + i + " cats"` would be equivalent to `new StringBuilder().append("I have ").append(i).append(" cats").toString()`. JEP280 changes this to compile concatenation into invokedynamic instructions instead, which essentially moves the implementation of string concatenation into a library selected at runtime. This isn't an optimization per se, but it allows for more efficient string concatenation to be added in the future without recompilation.